# Saving a user session after logging in with SQL Server

Tags: java, android, sql-server, session

I am trying to make my application with **SQL Server**, but I do not know how to identify the user that has **logged in**, after *closing and opening the application*.

**Also identify the ID** of the user who has **logged in**, *after closing and opening the application*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
// to save  in SharedPreferences in Login
private static final String MY_PREFERENCES = "MyPreference";
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("username", "usernameValue");
editor.apply();

//to get data from SharedPreferences in Home Page
private static final String MY_PREFERENCES = "MyPreference";
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String username= SharedPreferences.getString("username", null);
```