# Saving a variable using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to record data with SharedPrefences I want to sign up for the "ChipNumberRooms" key in RecyclerView, which I've chosen. But it doesn't save the data. When I click RecyclerView, I want it to register.

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("...", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        final String chipNumberNew =prefs.getString("ChipNumberrr", "0");
}

      recyclerViewNew.addOnItemTouchListener(new ProductsNewAdapter(this,
                recyclerViewNew, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, final int position) {

                DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

DatabaseReference refRooms = mDatabase.child(chipNumberNew).child("Rooms");

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("...", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

                editor.putString("ChipNumberRooms", chipNumberNew);
                editor.commit();

                refRooms.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                     ....
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));
```

Comment: check following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824973/saving-a-user-session-after-logging-in-with-sql-server/56825141#56825141

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first of all, create an AppPreference class and create some getter and setter in your class like this :-

```
public class AppPrefrences {

            private static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
            private static SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor;


    public static String getUserName(Context ctx) {
            mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
            return mPrefs.getString("userName", "");
        }

        public static void setUserName(Context ctx, String value) {
            mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
            mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
            mPrefsEditor.putString("userName", value);
            mPrefsEditor.commit();
        }

public static void clearAllPreferences(Context ctx) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        mPrefsEditor.clear();
        mPrefsEditor.commit();
    }
        }
```

this is my code change code according to your need and set your values in methods in after that for getting value just call the get methods